# IFOA CS2 cases when compound Poisson Process is also a Poisson Process

Tags: poisson-process

$S_{t} = X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{Nt}$  is a compound Poisson process.
I know that when $X_{j}$ can only take value 0 or 1, $S_{t}$ is also Poisson process.

I can understand when $X_{j}$ = 1 for all j, $S_{t}$ is a Poisson Process. But why when some of $X_{j}$ = 0, $S_{t}$ is also Poisson Process?